# Issues with solarized and Terminal.app

Tags: vim, terminal

I really apologize because I know that this question has been asked multiple times. I have gone through all of the previous questions, but I still have yet to have any luck setting up the Solarized colorscheme in my Terminal.app for OS X Mountain Lion. So far this is what I have:
[image]

My .vimrc currently is set up like the following:

```
set number
syntax enable
set background="dark" 
colorscheme solarized
```

but for my MacVim I get this:

[image]

This is what I would like to have my Terminal.app display as well. The only thing that my .vimrc says for MacVim is

```
colorscheme solarized
```

**Edit**

After I had asked this question, I eventually moved to [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/), which proved to be much nicer.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the newer versions of OS X terminal will support 256 colors out of the box.

Comment: Did you go through the [instructions](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/README.md) in the _osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized_ directory? It requires more than vimrc changes, you need to mod Terminal.app

Comment: I was under the impression that terminal.app did not need to be modified, as the terminal now supports the 256 colors in Lion and ML.

Comment: What is the response to `echo $TERM` in your Terminal.app?

Comment: This issue came up for me and the problem was that I had multiple solarized installations (eg, I just copied the color scheme file into .vim/colors, but also installed the plugin). I removed everything and reinstalled with just the plugin and it worked

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue, then I downloaded an alternate implementation of the [Solarized theme for the Mountain Lion terminal](https://github.com/tomislav/osx-lion-terminal.app-colors-solarized), and this appears to have solved it.

Answer (score 10):

Just add `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` to your vimrc

Comment: this completely fixed it for me. Why oh why solarized wasn't defaulting to 256 is beyond me. Is it naturally 16 colors?

Comment:  for this, after years of terminal envy and pink/green/purple

Answer (score 6):

Ensure that `TERM` is set to `xterm-256color` to let Vim know that the terminal supports 256 colors. This is the default for Terminal in Lion 10.7 and later†, so your preferences were customized at some point.

To tell Terminal to set `TERM` to a different value, go to

> **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Advanced**

and change `Declare terminal as:` to `xterm-256color`.

[Note that all this preference does is set the value of the `TERM` environment variable. It does not alter the behavior of Terminal or affect what sort of terminal it emulates.]

† Prior to Lion, the default was `xterm-color`.

Answer (score 4):

Add to your `~/.vimrc`

```
" Solarized Dark
syntax enable
set t_Co=256
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

This works on both ansi and xterm-256color versions of Solarized. Tested on Terminal 2.3 on a new OS X 10.8.5 VM installation.

*NB This answer supersedes the previous one that proposed changes to the profile swatches. I recently realised I had these commands in my `.vimrc` file that actually configured Solarized.*

Answer (score 1):

To run vim with 256 colors you must use a 256 color terminal. You can set your terminal to `xterm-256color`, for example, with `export TERM=xterm-256color` and then start vim. You can export this `$TERM` setting in one of your terminal startup scripts (e.g. .bashrc, .zshrc, etc.).

Comment: I have already ensured that terminal has been set to run 256 colors. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same trouble.

Comment: See the other answer and make sure you don't have `set term` anywhere in your vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem counterintuitive, but use `set g:solarized_termcolors=16`. This is confirmed to be the correct setting with `:h solarized`.